# JBoss switchyard problems with pom.xml

Tags: maven, jboss, switchyard

I have a JBoss EAP 6.1 with switchyard tools installed on it. When I make a new project in JBoss Studio 11.0.3 and like to recompile the project I got this kind of error:

[WARNING] The POM for org.switchyard:switchyard-plugin:jar:1.1.1-p5 is missing, no dependency information available

[Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S62s.jpg)

The problem is that I can't find some working example to be able to recompile with mvn clean install or mvn install.

here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.switchyard</groupId>
    <artifactId>switchyard-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>com.example.switchyard:switchyard-example</name>

    <properties>
        <switchyard.version>1.1.1-p5</switchyard.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-bean</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-api</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-transform</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-validate</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-test</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.switchyard.components</groupId>
            <artifactId>switchyard-component-test-mixin-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.switchyard</groupId>
                <artifactId>switchyard-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${switchyard.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannerClassNames>
                        <param>org.switchyard.transform.config.model.TransformSwitchYardScanner</param>
                    </scannerClassNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have followed some tutorials from WEB but have the same problem. 
Thank you for any kind of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is saying that maven can't find a 1.1.1-p5 switchyard-plugin.    Three choices:

a) Use an available community version (1.1.0.Final, etc) (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.switchyard/switchyard-plugin)

b) Use 1.1.1-p5.redhat-1 - that's the version I would have expected JBDS to have configured, but maybe I'm missing something  :  (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.switchyard/switchyard-plugin/1.1.1-p5-redhat-1)

c) Build the 1.1.1-p5 switchyard-plugin (git@github.com:jboss-switchyard/core.git, git checkout 1.1.1-p5)